# Close/NAA/VLQ flags: Helpful/Disputed/Declined outcome change

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools

This is a follow-up to: [(Flags) Leave Open ~ Declined, Looks OK ~ Disputed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335331/1292069)

> A long time ago, both types of flags had the same type of behavior. Both would place the post into the respective community review queue and the private moderator flag queue:
>
> 1. If review comes to a positive consensus or if the flag is manually reviewed by a moderator who decides the flag is correct, the flag is marked **helpful**.
> 2. If community review disagrees with taking action on the post, and a moderator doesn't handle it from the moderator flag queue, the flag is marked **disputed**.
> 3. If a moderator disagrees with the flag from their private moderator flag queue, the flag is marked **declined**.
>
> However, the system was later changed to never put recommend closure flags in the private moderator queue, as this effectively granted a privilege to lower-rep users that wasn't granted to higher-rep users (the ability to have a potential closure reviewed straight by a moderator). The third outcome above would thus never occur, and so recommend closure flags could never be marked declined. So SE simply changed the system so that a negative community review consensus would mark the flag as **declined** rather than **disputed**.

But I would like a change in the outcome behavior so that both the close flags and the NAA/VLQ flags can be dismissed in the same way:

1. If the final result of the review was "close/delete", AND the whole review was complete, the flag is marked **helpful**.
2. If the review is fully completed but the final result was "leave open / looks OK" (but some users may have voted to close/delete), the flag is marked **disputed**.
3. If the review was UNANIMOUSLY "leave open / looks OK", or if a moderator declines it via the mod flag queue (for answers only), the flag is marked **declined**.

This would also make the review results more explicit and accurate to the flagger. [Related.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105391/1292069)

---

UPDATE: [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) according to the first answer. But still (in my opinion) a UNIVERSAL "looks OK" outcome on a LQP review should mark the flag as **DECLINED** rather than **disputed**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's kind of how it already works. The text you are citing is not how close flags get dismissed. Current workings:

- If a single reviewer casts a close vote for the same reason as you, the flag is resolved as helpful. The review does not need to be completed and the final result will not change the flag status.
- If review completes with a result of the question getting closed, all remaining flags are resolved as helpful.
- If review completes with the result of leaving the question open, all remaining flags are resolved as declined.

So, in reality, you only need one person to agree with you and it will be considered helpful. Your flag can only be declined if no reviewers ever agree with you.

Your logic for resolving flags as disputed would only catch two edge cases:

- You flagged for closure, it accumulated close votes, but those close votes were only for reasons which you did not choose. The ultimate review consensus was to leave it open. Arguably, this isn't even an edge case since it suggests you chose an inappropriate reason to close the question.
- You flagged for closure after others had already cast close votes in an existing review task, and further reviews only opted to leave the question open.

Given that, I don't see the benefit in making the logic even more complicated when it is already so easy for it to be resolved as helpful in the first place.

Comment: That's true for close flags, but not for NAA/VLQ (which can only be disputed in review, and require moderator action to decline).  The question would be better if it left close flags out of it, I think.

Comment: I don't see this question as requesting any change to the LQP review outcomes. Those ones already provide a path for becoming disputed. From the context, it seems like they were specifically asking for a new path for Close Votes reviews to also dismiss as disputed, to match the behavior of other flags.

Comment: Yeah, on re-reading it, you're right that it's asking for more than I initially read it as.  If it were harmonized exactly as described, it would have the benefit of making it possible for reviewers to decline flags in LQP like you can in close vote review, but I agree with your response that fully harmonizing it probably isn't the best way to achieve that.

Comment: Ok but still (in my opinion) an UNANIMOUS "Looks OK" outcome on NAA/VLQ should mark the flag as **DECLINED** rather than **disputed**.